# JQuery image pop up code, removing classes on click refusing to work

Tags: jquery, css

So I am creating a feature that will enlarge the image when it is clicked on, and shrink the image back when clicked again.

This is the basic CSS for both the large and small images:

```
.bigpic {
position: absolute;
width:40%;
z-index: 100;
}
.smallpic {
width:20%;
}
```

And this is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.smallpic').click(function() {
    $('.bigpic').removeClass('bigpic');
    $(this).removeClass('smallpic');
    $(this).addClass('bigpic');
    $('body').append("<button class='imgbutton'>Close</button>");
    })

$('.bigpic').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('smallpic');
    $(this).removeClass('bigpic');
    })
$('.imgbutton').click(function() {
    $('.bigpic').addClass('smallpic')
    $('.smallpic').removeClass('bigpic')
})
});
```

As you can see i made it add 'biopic' and remove 'smallpic' classes, I also tried as an alternate method, adding a button that would close it. However neither methods of clicking the image, or the button, will return the image to its prior state.

Comment: Add semicolons after click() evt bindings

Comment: @EricLease I'm a bit forgetful about that sometimes, thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the time you are binding the event handlers, the elements do not have those classes, so the event handlers are not bound to them.

One way to solve this is to use event delegation. Another way would be to change your logic.

With event delegation, you bind the handler to an ancestor of the elements, but have the handler execute only when the `click` event originates on those elements:

```
$(document).on('click', '.smallpic', function() {
    $('.bigpic').removeClass('bigpic');
    $(this).removeClass('smallpic');
    $(this).addClass('bigpic');
    $('body').append("<button class='imgbutton'>Close</button>");
});

$(document).on('click', '.bigpic', function() {
    $(this).addClass('smallpic');
    $(this).removeClass('bigpic');
});
```

But perhaps a better way would be to add a `pic` class to all the image elements and bind a single event handler. You can use `.toggleClass()` to toggle the classes or even use `.hasClass()` to perform other conditional logic.

```
$('.pic').click(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    $img.toggleClass('bigpic');
    $img.toggleClass('smallpic');
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that made many things a whole lot clearer! Glad there's an easy solution to the problem I've been trying to fix for a week now.. :D

Comment: @JohnS This might have been true in older versions of jQuery where `.bind`, `.live`. and `.delegate` were required to attach event handlers as elements were added to the DOM.  However, as of v1.7 event delegation takes place automatically with `.on`.  And `.click` and `.on('click')` are interchangeable.  So most of this answer is a red herring if using a relatively modern version of jQuery.

Comment: @EricLease - Event delegation does not happen automatically with `.on()`; You must bind the event to the ancestor element and then supply the `selector` parameter to identify the descendants. From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events): "If `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as _direct_ or _directly-bound_. [...] When a `selector` is provided, the event handler is referred to as _delegated_." If you compare the code in the question to the code in my answer, you will see I did not just change `.click(` to `.on('click',`.

Answer (score 2):

How about toggling between the classes:

```
$('.imgbutton').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('smallpic bigpic');
})
```

Comment: If only I knew this existed! Helped a lot, thanks :)